# error in a view file of web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

```
#model:
db.define_table('dept',
                Field('name',unique=True,label='Department Name'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('course',
                Field('dept_id','reference dept'),
                Field('name',unique=True,label='Course Name'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('files',
                Field('course_id', 'reference course'),
                Field('documentx_filename',unique=True),
                Field('documentx','upload'))


#controller:

# list all departments
def show_dept():
    rows = db().select(db.dept.ALL)
    return dict(rows=rows)

def show_dept_course():
    z = db(request.args(0) == db.dept.id).select()
    courses = db(request.args(0) == db.course.dept_id).select()
    return locals()

#view:(show_dept_course.html)

{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h1>This is the x/show_dept_course.html template</h1>
<h3>
    Name of dept:
</h3>

{{for x in courses:}}
<h3>
{{=x.name}}
</h3>

{{pass}}
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

in view if I leave

```
Name of dept = (empty)
```

everything works as expected but if I replace it with:

```
Name of dept:{{=z.name}}
```

I get error:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'Rows' object has no attribute 'name'
```

where as in bottom

```
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

I can see under z that dept.name is displaying. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
Name of dept:{{=z[0].name}}
```

Comment: `z = db(request.args(0) == db.dept.id).select()` this is return a resultset as list like [<Row1>]. You can try like `z = db(request.args(0) == db.dept.id).select().fetchone()` or `.first()` depends on orm which were you used. Then you directly use like `z.name`.

Comment: Depends on web2py orm `z = db(request.args(0) == db.dept.id).select().first()` is preferred to fetch single row.

Comment: @shunya : If you can, try to use meaningful variables names in your code. `first_dept = db(request.args(0) == db.dept.id).select().first()` in the view and `Name of dept:{{=first_dept.name}}` is more readable than `z=[.....]` and Name of dept:{{=z.name}}